# What is $\lim_{x\to 0}\int_{0}^x\frac{e^{u^2}-1}{x^3}du?$

Tags: calculus

What is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_{0}^x\frac{e^{u^2}-1}{x^3}du?$$

Thanks very much!

---

> Does it holds:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_{0}^x\frac{e^{u^2}-1}{x^3}du = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^x(e^{u^2}-1) du?
> ?$$

Comment: For me the easiest way is to write $e^{u^{2}} = 1 + u^{2} + \mathcal{O}(u^{4})$. You will quickly get the limit $1/3$. Otherwise you can utilize L'Hospital's rule 3 times or fewer.

Comment: >Does it holds:

>$$\lim_{x\to 0}\int_{0}^x\frac{e^{u^2}-1}{x^3}du = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^3}\int_{0}^x(e^{u^2}-1) du?
?$$

Comment: Yes, it does ! And remember FTC if you use L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your second question, yes that is valid. $x$ is constant with respect to the integrating variable $u$, so that $\frac{1}{x^3}$ may be pulled out front of the integral.

For your limit, by L'Hospital and the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, you have $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x^2}-1}{3x^2}$$ Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^t = \sum_{k=0} { t^k \over k!} $, we have, for $|t| \le {1 \over 2}$, the estimate  $|e^t-1-t| \le \sum_{k=2} { |t|^k \over k!} \le \sum_{k=2} { |t|^k } \le t^2 { 1 \over 1 - |t|} \le 2 t^2$, and so, if $|u| \le {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, we have $|e^{u^2}-1-u^2| \le 2 u^4$.

Hence we have, for $|x| \le {1 \over \sqrt{2}}$, $| \int_0^x (e^{u^2}-1-u^2) du |
= | (\int_0^x (e^{u^2}-1) du)-{1 \over 3} x^3 |
\le | \int_0^x |e^{u^2}-1-u^2| du | 
\le {2 \over 5} |x|^5$. (Note the extra set of $|\cdot|$ to account for the fact that for $x<0$, then $\int_0^x f(t)dt = - \int_x^0 f(t) dt$.)

In particular, if $x \in (0,{1 \over \sqrt{2}}]$, we have
$| (\int_0^x {(e^{u^2}-1) \over x^3} du)-{1 \over 3}  | \le {2 \over 5} x^2 $,
from which it follows that 
$\lim_{x \to 0} \int_0^x {(e^{u^2}-1) \over x^3} du = {1 \over 3}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Frankly, it never occurred to me!